# Partial admin automation in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, automation, excel-2010, finance

I'm trying to make an excel expression that would automate the numbering of the types of financial transactions my school business makes. There are three types; "PPD", "VPD", and "VBU". As you can see in the picture below, each type has to be numbered correspondingly to their order.

I would like to be able to have one column with the excel expression which would calculate the numbers on its own, thus I'd only need to put in the type. I think I should somehow procedurally check for the cell above to see if it has the same type(ppd, vpd, vbu), and if it has, just add 1 to the cell adjacent. But I don't know how to do the "procedural" part...

Of course I don't need to do it, and I'm probably spending more time trying to automate it, than if I just typed it by hand, but where's the fun in that?

The layout of the cells, and their corresponding text

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it ...

In Cell B2 enter the formula:

```
=A2 & " " & TEXT(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2),"00")
```

and fill down.

[image]